# How to format elements of lists by splitting '\n'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, string-formatting

I have the list

```
col3_data = ['Hi','Good\nMorning','My\nfriend','Sam']
```

I want to format the list in a way such that elements containing \n only display the first line.

expected output:

```
['Hi','Good','My','Sam']
```

I tried using :

```
desired_list = [x.split('\n')[1:] for x in col3_data]
```

But I didn't get the desired result

Comment: ``[i.split()[0] for i in col3_data]`` ?

Comment: ``[1:]`` is exactly the opposite of what you want

Comment: or also `list(map(lambda s: s.split('\n')[0], col3_data))`

Comment: @rv.kvetch `map`  is very expensive. Avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this should work

```
    col3_data = ['Hi', 'Good\nMorning', 'My\nfriend', 'Sam']

    newl = []
     for x in col3_data:

         newl.append((x.split("\n",1)[0]))

      print(newl)
```

Will give

```
['Hi', 'Good', 'My', 'Sam']
```

Comment: props for doing a max split of 1 - ever slightly more efficient, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You have issue woth `x.split('\n')[1:]` this line. It should be `x.split('\n')[:1][0]` or `[x.split('\n')[0]`

**Try this:**

```
col3_data = ['Hi','Good\nMorning','My\nfriend','Sam']

desired_list = [x.split('\n')[:1][0] for x in col3_data]

# OR

desired_list = [x.split('\n')[0] for x in col3_data]

print(desired_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['Hi', 'Good', 'My', 'Sam']
```

Comment: Maybe I donn't understand, what's the point of `[:1][0]` here?

Comment: Used `[:1][0]` to avoid list type output

Comment: hmm... but wouldn't `[0]` be easier? I don't know when you'd ever use the former, I mean.

Comment: Yeah but I try to fix the issue that @Atom face with his existing code in slicing list. :)